# Change the height of multiple tags using JS

Tags: javascript, html, tags, attributes

I have several `<svg>` tags in my html document and I'm programmatically changing the heights of all of these using javascript. I have the following code which works successfully, but it only targets the first svg.

```
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].getAttribute('height'); 
  var svgHeight = parseFloat(x) + 30;
  document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].setAttribute('height', svgHeight);
```

How do I target the remaining svg tags? Any help would be great.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName#Example

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')
```

gives you an array of all svg Elements on the page. You can loop through them with a simple for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    array[i].setAttribute('height', svgHeight);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var svgs = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');

for (var i = 0; i < svgs.length; i++)
{
  var current = svgs[i];
  var svgHeight = parseFloat(current.getAttribute('height')) + 30;
  current.setAttribute('height', svgHeight);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for downvote. Care to explain? XD It's really funny.

Comment: No explanation = isn't an answer? How is that? : O

Comment: I wouldn't bet on that. He didn't know that [0] selects the first item from the array the document selector gives him.

Comment: Okay, you've got a point, but I've specified declared variable called `current` which depends on current index. It should make things clearer for him.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Daniel. I understood how it worked from the code. Although, I have another problem which has cropped up. The height only changes if I have an alert in the code before the setAttribute. It's like the page is asking for a prompt before applying the new settings. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: No, I don't have idea why this could happen.

Comment: I'd guess the page isn't loaded before you change the height. Does it work if you put this code in `window.onload=function(){ /* code */ }` ?

Comment: Thanks @MrBurger, I tried that but it didn't work. The SVG is generated by Javascript itself using a chart plugin.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.